# How to parse a csv file and store datails in java bean class

Tags: java, csv

I need to parse a csv file and store the data into a java bean class. Like:

```
email,fname,lname
imr@gmail.com,abc,xyz
```

These details into a bean class. I am able to parse a csv file. How to store details in bean class.

```
private static List<List<String>> readTXTFile(String csvFileName) throws IOException {

     String line = null;
    BufferedReader stream = null;
    List<List<String>> csvData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

    try {
        stream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileName));
        while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitted = line.split(",");
            List<String> dataLine = new ArrayList<String>(splitted.length);
            for (String data : splitted)
                dataLine.add(data);
            csvData.add(dataLine);
        }
    } finally {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.close();
    }

    return csvData;

}
```

the above code is parsing csv file but i want that data to be inserted in java bean class.

Comment: Instead adding the elements to a List (dataLine) add them to the bean and then add the bean to csvData (changing the generic from List<String> to your bean class)

Comment: I don't see your bean class code, so how should we know how to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a POJO

```
private class Data{//You can make it public too, in a separate class
    String email;
    String fname;
    String lname;

    //Getters

    //Setters
}
```

In your original class you can use like this

```
List<Data> datas = new ArrayList<Data>();
try {
    stream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFileName));
    while ((line = stream.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] splitted = line.split(",");
        Data data = new Data();
        data.setEmail(splitted[0]);
        data.setFname(splitted[1]);
        data.setLname(splitted[2]);

        datas.add(data);
    }
}
```

You will have all rows in your arraylist. You can put a null check to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use a OpenCSV

Writing

```
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.csv"), ',');
        String[] headers = {"id","name","address"};
        writer.writeNext(headers);
```

Reading(The example of setting inside the bean and add to list)

USER_ID_INDEX etc is constant

```
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(userManActionForm.getUploadFile().getInputStream()));
    List<String[]> entries = reader.readAll();
    List<Member> memberList = new ArrayList<Member>();
        for (String[] entry : entries) {
            Member member = new Member();
            member.setUserId(entry[USER_ID_INDEX]);
            member.setUserName(entry[USER_NAME_INDEX]);
            member.setGroup(entry[USER_GROUP_INDEX]);
            memberList.add(member);
        }
```

https://code.google.com/p/opencsv/