# How to store substrings from .docx to java bean class?

Tags: java, javabeans, docx

I would need to create java bean class from strings which are read from .docx file. The docx file looks like:

```
Comments:
20.6.2018 16:18-16:25 problem: first problem, action first action
20.6.2018 16:20-16:45 problem: second problem, action: second action
20.6.2018 16:25-16:30 problem:  third problem, action: third action
Check list based on data from 24.6.2018.
```

I created a CheckList Class to read the docx where I used the instance of FAData.class POJO to set its instant variables according to [How to parse a csv file and store datails in java bean class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755838/how-to-parse-a-csv-file-and-store-datails-in-java-bean-class)

```
public class CheckList {

    String Check;
    ArrayList<String> ActionG = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> ProblemG = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> DateG = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> BeginTimeG = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> EndTimeG = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void readDocxFile(String fileName) {
        FAData data = new FAData(); // instance of FAData POJO
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(fis);
            List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();
            String Comments = "";
            for (XWPFParagraph para : paragraphs) {
                Comments = Comments.concat(para.getText() + "\n");
            }
            Check = Comments.substring(Comments.lastIndexOf("Check"), Comments.length());  // split the last sentence
            String CommentsG = Comments.substring(Comments.indexOf(":") + 1, Comments.lastIndexOf("Check")); // split the sentences between „Comments:” and the last sentence

            data.setCheck(Check);   // add the Check instant variable to FAData POJO 

            if (!CommentsG.equals("")) {      // check if sentences exist between „Comments:” and the last sentence
// add the substrings to ArrayLists

                String[] FAG = CommentsG.split("\n");
                for (int i = 1; i < FAG.length; i++) {
                    ActionG.add(FAG[i].substring(FAG[i].indexOf("action") + 7, FAG[i].length()));
                    ProblemG.add(FAG[i].substring(FAG[i].indexOf("problem") + 9, FAG[i].indexOf("action") - 2));
                    DateG.add(FAG[i].substring(0, 10));
                    BeginTimeG.add(FAG[i].substring(FAG[i].indexOf(":") - 2, FAG[i].indexOf("-")));
                    EndTimeG.add(FAG[i].substring(FAG[i].indexOf("-") + 1, FAG[i].indexOf("-") + 6));
                }
            }
// add the ArrayList instant variables to FAData POJO
            data.setActionG(ActionG);
            data.setProblemG(ProblemG);
            data.setDateG(DateG);
            data.setBeginTimeG(BeginTimeG);
            data.setEndTimeG(EndTimeG);

            fis.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class FAData {
    String Check;
    ArrayList<String> ActionG = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> ProblemG = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> DateG = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> BeginTimeG = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> EndTimeG = new ArrayList<String>();

    public String getCheck() {
        return Check;
    }

    public void setCheck(String Check) {
        this.Check = Check;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getActionG() {
        return ActionG;
    }

    public void setActionG(ArrayList<String> ActionG) {
        this.ActionG = ActionG;
    }
    ....
    //Getter and Setter for the rest variables 
}
```

I tested if the variables are available from FAData.class:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CheckList TC = new CheckList();
        String fileName = "c:\\path\\to\\docx";
        try {

            TC.readDocxFile(fileName);
            FAData datas = new FAData();
            String testCheck = datas.getCheck();
            ArrayList<String> testDate = datas.getDateG();

            System.out.println(testCheck);
            System.out.println(testDate);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

but I got null values. I do not know what I did wrong or how I should thest FAData.class. Could someone give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meantime I figured out the solution. I added the `List<FAData> datas = new ArrayList<FAData>();` inside `readDocxFile` method and added to it the `data` values:

```
datas.add(data);
```

If I create a new instant of CheckList object in an other class I can get the data e.g:

```
CheckList TC = new CheckList();
    List<FAData> D = TC.readDocxFile(fileName);

    String DateG = D.get(0).getDateG(0);
```